# show aspxtreelist progressbar when copy files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to show the change of progressbar in column of aspxtreelist when click on button "copy" and start copy the files.

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Session("FolderPath1") = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Session("FolderPath2") = TextBox2.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub list_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
ASPxTreeList4.DataBind()
ASPxTreeList4.DataSource = Session("FolderPath2") & Session("FolderPath1")
ASPxTreeList4.ExpandAll()
End Sub

Protected Sub ASPxTreeList4_VirtualModeNodeCreating(sender As Object, e As TreeListVirtualModeNodeCreatingEventArgs)
Dim nNodePath As String = e.NodeObject.ToString()
' Assign a unique identifier to each node based on its path
e.NodeKeyValue = GetNodeGuid(nNodePath)
' Determine if the node is a leaf (file) or has children (directory)
e.IsLeaf = Not Directory.Exists(nNodePath)
' Set the node's display name
e.SetNodeValue("name", Path.GetFileName(nNodePath))
End Sub

Protected Sub ASPxTreeList4_VirtualModeCreateChildren(sender As Object, e As TreeListVirtualModeCreateChildrenEventArgs)
Dim children As New List(Of Object)()

' Check if the current node is the root node (no parent)
If e.NodeObject Is Nothing Then
' Retrieve the root paths from session
Dim rootPath As String = Convert.ToString(Session("FolderPath1"))
Dim rootPath2 As String = Convert.ToString(Session("FolderPath2"))

' Add root paths as nodes if they are valid directories
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rootPath) AndAlso Directory.Exists(rootPath) Then
children.Add(rootPath)
End If
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rootPath2) AndAlso Directory.Exists(rootPath2) Then
children.Add(rootPath2)
End If
Else

Dim path As String = e.NodeObject.ToString()
If Directory.Exists(path) Then
' Add directories
For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(path)
If Not IsSystemName(dir) Then children.Add(dir)
Next
' Add files
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(path)
If Not IsSystemName(file) Then children.Add(file)
Next
End If
End If
e.Children = children
End Sub

Protected Sub copyf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim folderPath1 As String = Convert.ToString(Session("FolderPath1"))
Dim folderPath2 As String = Convert.ToString(Session("FolderPath2"))

' Check that the directories exist
If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath1) OrElse Not Directory.Exists(folderPath2) Then
Return
End If

' Get lists of file names in each directory
Dim filesInFolder1 As New HashSet(Of String)(Directory.GetFiles(folderPath1).Select(Function(f) Path.GetFileName(f)))
Dim filesInFolder2 As New HashSet(Of String)(Directory.GetFiles(folderPath2).Select(Function(f) Path.GetFileName(f)))

' Determine which files need to be copied in each direction
Dim filesToCopyToFolder2 = filesInFolder1.Except(filesInFolder2).ToList()
Dim filesToCopyToFolder1 = filesInFolder2.Except(filesInFolder1).ToList()

' Copy files from folder1 to folder2
For Each file In filesToCopyToFolder2
Dim sourcePath = Path.Combine(folderPath1, file)
Dim destPath = Path.Combine(folderPath2, file)
' Placeholder for actual copy method
CopyFileAndUpdateProgress(sourcePath, destPath)
Next

' Copy files from folder2 to folder1
For Each file In filesToCopyToFolder1
Dim sourcePath = Path.Combine(folderPath2, file)
Dim destPath = Path.Combine(folderPath1, file)
' Placeholder for actual copy method
CopyFileAndUpdateProgress(sourcePath, destPath)
Next

End Sub

' Placeholder for a method to copy a file and update the progress bar
Private Sub CopyFileAndUpdateProgress(sourcePath As String, destPath As String)

File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath)

End Try
End Sub
**************
<div style="padding: 50px;">
    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel11" runat="server" Text="Folder1 Path: " Font-Size="30px" ForeColor="White"></dx:ASPxLabel>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="300px" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel12" runat="server" Text="Folder2 Path: " Font-Size="30px" ForeColor="White"></dx:ASPxLabel>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="300px" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="list" runat="server" Text="list folders" OnClick="list_Click"  />
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="copyf" runat="server" Text=" copy" OnClick="copyf_Click"   />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <dx:ASPxTreeList ID="ASPxTreeList4" runat="server" Width="100%" OnVirtualModeCreateChildren="ASPxTreeList4_VirtualModeCreateChildren"
                OnVirtualModeNodeCreating="ASPxTreeList4_VirtualModeNodeCreating" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="name" Caption="File name" />
                    <dx:TreeListProgressBarColumn AutoFilterCondition="Default" ShowInFilterControl="Default" VisibleIndex="1">
                        <PropertiesProgressBar DisplayFormatString=""></PropertiesProgressBar>
                    </dx:TreeListProgressBarColumn>
                </Columns>
                <SettingsBehavior AutoExpandAllNodes="True" />
            </dx:ASPxTreeList>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="list" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="copyf" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

I try to active `TreeListProgressBarColumn` while copying file when click button copy